Is partitioning beneficial for CRM-like design with virtual tables and their values?
Imagine schema like this:
CREATE TABLE owner(
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(200) not null
);

CREATE TABLE table_with_values(
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(200) not null,
  owner_id bigint REFERENCES owner
);

CREATE TABLE int_value(
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(300) not null,
  value int not null,
  table_id bigint REFERENCES table_with_values
);

CREATE TABLE double_value(
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(300) not null,
  value decimal not null,
  table_id bigint REFERENCES table_with_values
);

CREATE TABLE string_value(
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(300) not null,
  value varchar(600) not null,
  table_id bigint REFERENCES table_with_values
);

INSERT INTO owner (name) values ('Jack');

INSERT INTO table_with_values (name, owner_id) VALUES ('Configuration A', 1);

INSERT INTO int_value (name, value, table_id) VALUES ('NumberOfCars', 22, 1);
INSERT INTO string_value (name, value, table_id) VALUES ('MajorCarCompany', 'Hello World', 1);
INSERT INTO double_value (name, value, table_id) VALUES ('Price', 2.22, 1);

SELECT * from int_value;
SELECT * from string_value;
SELECT * from double_value;

I'm wondering about partitioning because data can grow suddenly and in huge numbers, meaning one "owner" can have thousands of tables, and tables can have thousands of "values".
The exact schema differs, but I think you get the idea. It would be enough if one or two owners imported billions of rows into the system without proper preparation and it would croak.
The goal is to be prepared for growth with the help of partitioning, if it can help at all.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

What specifically do you hope to achieve from Partitioning? There are some specific use cases it's meant for, but it's not an end all performance improvement feature, like some people confusingly think.

Don't do this - it has an EAV smell about it.

@Vérace can you elaborate please? Don't do what? And what are the options in terms of system like this? I mean the end goal to have a flexible system with ability to have "virtual tables with values".

@J.D. currently re-reading through PostgreSQL documentation, Partitioning chapter. It seems that "early on partitioning design" can be a benefit in terms of growing database. I'm wondering how this schema can benefit from partitioning.

@idchlife Yea but you're missing the "how, when, and why" that's so. Partitioning is not a performance enhancement feature for DQL or most DML types of queries (such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). Indexes solve that problem appropriately and magnitudes more efficiently than Partitioning. This is something many people falsely get confused on. Partitioning is a database management tool and can help with dropping / truncating whole partitions at a time when you have rolling data or data you archived already, or performance with things like indexing and backups of individual partitions.

@J.D. this part (last paragraph) confused me: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-BEST-PRACTICES
It seems that partitioning later on, when you have billions of rows, will be painfully slow to execute.
Anyway, indexing is a must and a huge improvement for tables like that. I just thought about partitioning by range: "1 - 1_000_000 table_id", "1_000_000 - 2_000_000 table_id", etc.
The data will grow, and I wonder how I can adapt to it in advance.

@idchlife If you decide you need Partitioning later on, then yes, it's harder to enable when your table is huge. But unless you foresee you'll truncate / drop individual partitions, or do data management on individual partitions like backups, there's not much of a need for Partitioning anyway (which is most people's use cases). Partitioning has limitations and can be a pain to manage too. Again, it's not meant for improving performance of queries such as SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and can even slow them down sometimes. Indexing significantly improves performance of those use cases...

...because it partitions the data exponentially as opposed to linearly like the Partition feature does. A valid index can get you any subset of rows from a huge table with trillions of records in a few milliseconds time. I've worked with tables in the 10s of billions and performance for DQL and DML types of queries was just as good as when the tables had 100s of rows, because they were Indexed properly. So again, the question is what problem are you trying to solve with Partitioning? If it's purely for performance reasons, especially for DQL/DML types queries, then it's the wrong tool.

@J.D. Can you please post this as an answer? I think your point is valid and can help people in the future who come to this question.
